# Can't parse a certain information from some html elements using xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I've created an xpath expression to target an element so that I can extract a certain information out of some html elements using xpath within scrapy. I can't reach it anyway.

Html elements:

```
<div class="rates">
                <label>
                  Rates :
                </label>
                  R 3500
                  <br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
              </div>
```

I wish to extract `R 3500` out of it.

I've tried with:

```
from scrapy import Selector

html = """
<div class="rates">
                <label>
                  Rates :
                </label>
                  R 3500
                  <br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
              </div>
"""
sel = Selector(text=html)
rate = sel.xpath("//*[@class='rates']/label/following::*").get()
print(rate)
```

Upon running my above script this is what I'm getting `<br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">` whereas I wish to get `R 3500`.

I could have used `.tail` if opted for `lxml`. However, when I go for scrapy I don't find anything similar.

***How can I extract that rate out of the html elements using xpath?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a *text* node as a **`following-sibling`** after the `label` node:

```
...
sel = Selector(text=html)
rate = sel.xpath("//*[@class='rates']/label/following-sibling::text()").get().strip()
print(rate)
```

The output:

```
R 3500
```

---

***Addition***: `"//*[@class='rates']/label/following::text()"` should also work.

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes

Comment: I found you in the loop after a long time @RomanPerekhrest. It perfectly worked. An optional question: do you know how i can achieve the same using css selector. Thankssssss a lot.

Comment: You could improve your answer by mentioning the reason why `following::*` does not work: `*` only selects _element_ nodes, not text nodes.

Comment: @MITHU, welcome. as for your question: we can't do that magic in css, but in python libraries we have `.next_sibling` in `Beautifulsoup` and `.tail` in `etree`

Comment: @MathiasMüller, see the addition, it should work with `"//*[@class='rates']/label/following::text()"` (tested)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! You still did not add an explanation, just point out another solution. An answer that gives the reason would be more educational.

Comment: @MathiasMüller, usually users ask "Why it doesn't work" on SO in specific cases, while this one clearly states "How can I extract ..."

Answer (score 1):

To complement the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56871967/1987598), which is entirely correct, here is an explanation why

```
//*[@class='rates']/label/following::*
```

given the document

```
<div class="rates">
   <label>
   Rates :
   </label>
   R 3500
   <br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
</div>
```

does *not* return the text `R 3500`: `*` only selects *element nodes* that follow after `label` elements, but not text nodes. Elements and text nodes are different concepts in the XPath document model. You can test this claim with a slightly different document:

```
<div class="rates">
   <label>
   Rates :
   </label>
   <any>R 3500</any>
   <br class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
</div>
```

Which causes your code to return the `any` element.

Both `text()` (more specific) and `node()` (more general) select this text node, and in this case both the `following::` and `following-sibling::` axes work.